# GitLab reference submodule in Readme.md

Tags: gitlab, markdown

A gitlab project [at](https://gitlab.com/JohanVdBerg/doc-test/tree/master) contain submodule and both the project and submodule also contain a readme.md file. The readme.md of the top project is given

```
Top Readme.md
=============

[Link to folder](folder)

[Link to submodule folder](sub)

[Link to submodule Readme.md](sub/README.md)
```

The first link work as the brower opens at the subfolder but the other two link does not work, I get a page not found message.

How do you create links to files in a submodule as well as to the submodule as is self?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try instead to use the full https URL (https://gitlab.com/JohanVdBerg/doc-submodule) for the `sub` or `sub/README.md` file.

Your main repo only includes a reference (called gitlink) to the submodule, not the file itself.

The OP adds:

> it is needed to point to the branch to which the submodule points to

Then the URLs would be:

- for `sub`: `https://gitlab.com/JohanVdBerg/doc-submodule/tree/<abranch>`
- for sub/README.md: `https://gitlab.com/JohanVdBerg/doc-submodule/blob/<abranch>/README.md`

Comment: I wonder if there can be a solution which handles for both cases of viewing locally and viewing on the web?

Comment: @DevenPhillips good question. Not that I know of.